# Assigning a domain name to localhost for development environment

Tags: node.js, macos, ssl, dns, ssl-certificate

I am building a website and would not like to reconfigure the website from pointing to `http://127.0.0.1` to `http://www.example.com`. Furthermore, the certificate that I am using is of course made with the proper domain name of `www.example.com` but my test environment makes calls to `127.0.0.1` which makes the security not work properly.

What I currently want to do is configure my development environment to assign the domain name `www.example.com` to `127.0.0.1` so that all `http://www.example.com/xyz` is routed to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/xyz` and `https://www.example.com/xyz` is routed to `https://127.0.0.1:8080/xyz`.

I am *not* using Apache. I am currently using node.js as my web server and my development environment is in Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: did you manage to figure this one out? I have the exact same question. I've been partially able to solve it using ngrok.

Comment: if you know the answer, please let me know

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If you edit your etc/hosts file you can assign an arbitrary host name to be set to 127.0.0.1.
Open up /etc/hosts in your favorite text editor and add this line:

```
127.0.0.1   www.example.com
```

Unsure of how to avoid specifying the port in the HTTP requests you make to example.com, but if you must avoid specifying that at the request level, you could run nodejs as root to make it listen on port 80.

Edit: After editing /etc/hosts, you may already have the DNS request for that domain cached. You can clear the cached entry by running this on the command line.

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Comment: This actually doesn't answer the OP question. The port is not forwarded, and using node as root, even in development mode, is not a good idea.

Comment: Here is a more thorough guide which includes the step of setting up the virtual host on either apache or nginx: https://emmapopoola.medium.com/setting-up-a-custom-domain-for-your-local-apps-mac-os-linux-c68798722143