# Node.js Express setup proxy for development environment, avoid localhost in url for Mac OS X

Tags: node.js, macos, portforwarding

I want to setup my dev environment so that all requests from `www.dev.com` in my browser are routed to `localhost:8080`.

I added `127.0.01 www.dev.com` in my /etc/host, but it doesn't do the port forwarding. If I go to `http://www.dev.com:8080/` it works, but I want/need to use `http://www.dev.com/` instead, which is closer to the actual production environment.

How do I do that? I tried several solutions like nginx, but I don't like it, I'd prefer it to be "scriptable", so that any other developer can use it directly. I'm using Express.js with Node.

I read through [Assigning a domain name to localhost for development environment on Mac OS X with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576217/assigning-a-domain-name-to-localhost-for-development-environment-on-mac-os-x-wit) but it actually doesn't explain the port-forwarding part.

Comment: Why not have your Node app listen on port 80 instead of 8080 (although it does require to run your Node app as root)?

Comment: Because running an app as root would be bad, because the behavior could be different from production. It's actually a very simple and bad way to go IMO. For instance, writing a file may work as root, but not in production, and therefore you wouldn't even know there is an issue until it hits production.

Comment: True, although any reasonable app that would run as root should drop privileges as soon as it has performed the thing it required root privs for (listening to port 80, for example). But the proposed answer is a much better solution. In your production environment, _something_ has to be listening on port 80 as well, so if you want a close match to what runs on production, you probably have to set up something very similar (reverse proxy?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Mac port forwarding. Binding to port 80 requires root privileges (anything below 1024(?) needs root) and it's probably best not to run a development application with root.

You can use `pfctl` port forwarding

e.g. To forward port 80 to 8080

```
echo "rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

source: https://salferrarello.com/mac-pfctl-port-forwarding/

You can also use `ipfw` (Not available on El Capitan)

```
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8080 tcp from any to any 80 in
```

Comment: Nice solution, although `ipfw` doesn't exist anymore (since El Capitan, I think).

Comment: `echo "rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080" | sudo pfctl -ef -` works perfectly for Yosemite! :)