# How to change the domain name on a local deployed React app

Tags: reactjs, dns

I have a react app running on localhost port 3000 but instead of using localhost:3000 I would like to set a custom domain name to mydomain.com. I did already the change in the windows host file to

`127.0.0.1   mydomain.com`

but I guess I have to specify in my react app to look into this domain instead of localhost. How can I do this?

I tried : `"start": "set HOST=videowall.com && set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start",`

but it is returning 
`Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND videowall.com`

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146086/how-can-i-develop-locally-using-a-domain-name-instead-of-localhost3000-in-the

Answer (score 18):

You need add this line to your hosts file:

- Unix/Linux : `/etc/hosts`
- Windows: `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 videowall.com
```

NOTE: If you need access this out of your development machine like me change `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`.

Use `.env` file in root of your React project instead of export/set envs, with this content:

```
HOST='videowall.com'
PORT=3006
```

That's it.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to delete the single quotes around the host name. So: HOST=videowall.com

Comment: Is there a way to do just videowall.com and not videowall.com:3000? I also do not want to run on default server root 80 on which apache runs.

Comment: @ArvindK. For production, you can set your env's in the `.env.production` file with `PORT=80` just for the `npm run build` but in development, by the `npm run start` you cannot bind port numbers below `1024`

Answer (score 5):

Make the following change in your package.json file

"start": "HTTPS=true HOST=mycompany.com PORT=3001 react-scripts start",

Answer (score 2):

In general `create-react-app` does assume it is hosted at the server root. If you would like to modify this behaviour, please refer to the [create react app documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths) for relative paths. You can specify it in your `package.json` under `homepage`.

```
"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath",
```

As of your description of the error I suggest that modifying your host file should be fine. You should check that the domain locally resolves to the correct IP.

On mac/unix try `traceroute mydomain.com`
On windows try `tracert mydomain.com`

Answer (score 1):

Add following link in your `host` file

Windows: `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

Linux: `/etc/hosts`

```js
127.0.0.1 mydomain.local
127.0.0.1 subdomain.mydomain.local
```

Add `HOST` in `.env` file

```js
// ..
HOST=mydomain.local
// ..
```

Run React App

`npm run start`

Visit: `mydomain.local`

Comment: This works clean! Should be accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **webpack** there is a property in `devServer` that is called `host`, you can change the hostname of the app there.