# React CRA: When adding subdomain on localhost it says: The development server has disconnected

Tags: reactjs, subdomain, create-react-app, fiddler

I am on a project with create-react-app without ejecting.
I wanted to have subdomains on localhost or a fake host for development.
When I added my host in windows hosts file it said invalid host header even if I add `HOST=mydevhost.com` `DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true` in `.env` file.
I couldn't make it work without using third party apps so I used Fiddler and it worked as expected now the sites comes up but instantly says:

> The development server has disconnected.
> Refresh the page if necessary.

The problem is that the fast refresh doesn't work now and I have to refresh the site every time I make a change. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong here? Should I even use something like Fiddler here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `react-app-rewired` and in `config-overrides.js` I added the subdomain to allowed host.  The final config looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, env) => {
    return config;
  },
  devServer: (configFunction) => (proxy, allowedHost) => {
    const devServerConfig = configFunction(proxy, allowedHost);

    devServerConfig.allowedHosts = ["subdomain.localhost"];
    return devServerConfig;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you can do that from your operating system to point your local domain to your react server, meaning that can create a local domain that points to the app server (host:port).

here's a guideline that may help:
https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/local-domain-names-ubuntu/

***Relevant answers***:
[How can I develop locally using a domain name instead of 'localhost:3000' in the url with create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146086/how-can-i-develop-locally-using-a-domain-name-instead-of-localhost3000-in-the)

Comment: Thanks but even if I add HOST in the .env file it still says Invalid Host Header.